# Vídeo não carrega externamente

Tags: iis, html5-video

Estou utilizando a tag video do HTML5 para carregar um vídeo .mp4, mas quando testo externamente o mesmo não carrega.
Verifiquei os MIME Types do servidor e está correto.
Servidor IIS 8.5.

Alguem tem alguma idéia do que pode estar acontecendo?

`<video width="400" controls autoplay>
     <source src="./assets/ComoIntegrarcoma.mp4"
    type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>`

Comment: O ideal seria você colocar parte do seu código pra ajudar na identificação de problemas/soluções (pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Se você acessar a url da mídia, ela baixa?